# Does a Kafka Sink Connector for CSV file currently exists?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need a kafka sink connector allowing the user to persist topic content as .CSV files. I've been investigating a while.

Confluent provides [FileSink](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-filestream/filestream_connector.html) connector which - as far as I understood - doesn't support CSV format. 
I've been playing a bit with 
[this project](https://github.com/dbtucker/kafka-connect-schemaedfile) but the sink task seems not implemented. Alongside, [this one](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir) actually implements just the Source part.

Does a project with this capability currently exists?

Comment: You need to write a consumer job to reprocess a topic data to CSV format. Upon which, the FileSink Connector can be applied... Otherwise, how would you expect fields to be written to CSV from JSON, Avro, or other binary format?

Comment: Also, FileSink is built into Apache Kafka, not Confluent https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using CSV? Is this for users to build Excel-analytics against, for example?

Comment: is there any kafka CSV sink available now?